# Enable "search:" Parameter in Custom Add-On Channel Entries Method (EE2)

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, add-on-development

I'm extending the Channel module `entries()` method in my custom plugin and am trying to figure out how to include the `search:` parameter. I get that the search parameters are an array accessed via `ee()->TMPL->search_fields`, but I can't figure out how to pass that data to the method. Here's what I have (simplified):

```
public function entries()
{
    $channel = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('channel');
    $search_fields = ee()->TMPL->search_fields;

    return $this->_channel_entries($channel, $search_fields);
}

private function _channel_entries( $channel='', $search_fields=array() )
{
    ee()->TMPL->tagparams = array(
        'channel' = $channel,
        'disable' = 'member_data|pagination|categories'
    );

    ee()->TMPL->search_fields = $search_fields;

    if (! class_exists('channel'))
  {
      require_once PATH_MOD.'channel/mod.channel.php';
  }

  $channel = new Channel;

  return $channel->entries();
}
```

How do I give the `entries()` method access to the `search_fields` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those methods are in your own plugin/module, then the `search:foo` parameters *won't* be added to the `search_fields` property. That only happens for the channel:entries tag. For any other tag, those parameters are present in the `ee()->TMPL->tagparams` array. So, to pass them on to the native Channel::entries(), read the param from the `tagparams` array, strip the `search:` prefix from the key, and set the `search_fields` array before calling the `entries` method.